# Count days worked per employee number in Excel

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2016

I have a timesheet entry form that people use to enter their hours worked per day. Sometimes they enter multiple entries per day because of different areas worked.

I want to count how many days worked based on the work date. There could be multiple entries per workdate.

For example:

```
Employee #       Date          Hours
12345            11/15/17      8
12345            11/16/17      4
12345            11/16/17      3
98765            11/15/17      2
98765            11/15/17      2
98765            11/15/17      2
```

I have a consolidated table that sums the hours worked per employee, but I also would like the days worked. So, for example:

```
Employee #       Hours         Days
12345            15            2
98765            6             1
```

I can't seem to put my finger on the right formula/combination of formulas to use. Countif would work perfectly if it worked similarly to sumif.

Comment: I would suggest that your try creating a pivot table from your data.  It will probably be much easier to answer such database style questions using a pivot table versus groping around with complex Excel formulas.

Comment: Yes it had crossed my mind that pivoting the data would be easier, but this spreadsheet is already complex and pivoting the entry data would screw with a lot of my other formulas and functions in the back end for payroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try `Advanced Filter`,then `COUNTIF` and `SUMIF`:

[image]

Hope this helps.